# Pygsr speech recognition error

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to use Pygsr, what I'm doing wrong?

```
from pygsr import Pygsr
speech = Pygsr()
speech.record(3) 
phrase, complete_response = speech.speech_to_text('es_ES') 
print (phrase)
```

but I got error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/VIV/PyCharm_project/0_WORKFILE_2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pygsr import Pygsr
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pygsr\__init__.py", line 30
    print "REC: "
                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Pygsr library seems to be written with some version of Python 2 in mind.

In Python 2, `print` is a statement and as such allows "softspace" in between the statement itself and the string to be printed. [As of Python 3.0, print is a function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function) and as such, requires opening and closing parentheses around the function arguments. Because Pygsr is written with some version of Python 2, it still uses the statement form of `print`, which is invalid in Python 3. This can be seen in the line that the `SyntaxError` is pointing to, which is a statement and not a function (`print "REC: "` vs `print("REC: ")`).

You've got a few options for fixing this issue:

The first option is to switch back down to using the latest version of Python 2 (which is 2.7.11 at time of writing). This will mean that anything that's not backwards compatible in 3 (but still works in 2) will function, but I don't recommend switching versions just to get a library working, especially because it will affect the code you write. As well as that, the general consensus (to the best of my knowledge) seems to be that new scripts built on 2 should use the function form of `print`, which is available from 2.6 onwards but can be imported from `__future__` for versions before 2.6.

The second option is to use the automatic tool [`2to3`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/2to3.html) to convert the scripts in the library to be compatible with 3. This won't always work 100% due to the complexity and potential edge cases that a Python script may have, but it's usually a good way to get a lot of the simpler changes out of the way quickly.

The third option is to make the changes yourself. This should be as simple as manually going through the library and fixing any references to `print`, but you could also find the issues by running your script, seeing which file and line number is referenced in the error and then making the required edits.

Comment: in code I have `print (phrase)` and error shows: `print "REC: "` I got this error even  without any print call:  `from pygsr import Pygsr
speech = Pygsr()
speech.record(3)
phrase, complete_response = speech.speech_to_text('es_ES')`  just like this I have same error:`print "REC: "
                ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'`
seems the problem here is something else

Comment: @Ai_ve the problem is not in your code, the problem is inside the Pygsr code. It is incompatible with your version of Python.

Comment: I'm looking for some useful recognition which can be used for gui and work without internet